# Using Spring @Async and ThreadPoolTaskScheduler with pool-size=1

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

We have a service implementation in our Spring-based web application that increments some statistics counters in the db. Since we don't want to mess up response time for the user we defined them asynchronous using Spring's @Async:

```
public interface ReportingService {

    @Async
    Future<Void> incrementLoginCounter(Long userid);

    @Async
    Future<Void> incrementReadCounter(Long userid, Long productId);
}
```

And the spring task configuration like this:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" />
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="10" />
```

Now, having the `pool-size="10"`, we have concurrency issues when two threads try two create the same initial record that will contain the counter.

Is it a good idea here to set the `pool-size="1"` to avoid those conflicts? Does this have any side affects? We have quite a few places that fire async operations to update statistics.

Comment: Ideally, any increment kind of operation, supposed to use thread safe, i.e. synchronize, just only for increment part. Rest of statement can be executed in Async.

Comment: If you do so, never ever use @Async for another kind of operation since it will use the same ThreadPoolExecutor, and thus be slown down by the ReportingService operations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The side-effects would depend on the speed at which tasks are added to the executor in comparison to how quickly a single thread can process them. If the number of tasks being added per second is greater than the number that a single thread can process in a second you run the risk of the queue increasing in size over time until you finally get an out of memory error.

Check out the **executor** section at this page [Task Execution](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). They state that having an unbounded queue is not a good idea.

If you know that you can process tasks faster than they will be added then you are probably safe. If not, you should add a queue capacity and handle the input thread blocking if the queue reaches this size.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the two examples you posted, instead of a constant stream of @Async calls, consider updating a JVM local variable upon client requests, and then have a background thread write that to the database every now and then. Along the lines of (mind the semi-pseudo-code):

```
class DefaultReportingService implements ReportingService {

    ConcurrentMap<Long, AtomicLong> numLogins;

    public void incrementLoginCounterForUser(Long userId) {
        numLogins.get(userId).incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Scheduled(..)
    void saveLoginCountersToDb() {
        for (Map.Entry<Long, AtomicLong> entry : numLogins.entrySet()) {
            AtomicLong counter = entry.getValue();
            Long toBeSummedWithTheValueInDb = counter.getAndSet(0L);
            // ...
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: this is a very good idea jukka. i think next time i will implement it this way. i accepted johns answer, just because the solution is based on my questions approach.

Comment: @fischermatte Did you try this approach? What happens if app crashes before all numLogins are written? Maybe this issue exists with the other solution(accepted answer)?